# Kubernetes hostPath volume not showing files

Tags: kubernetes

I'm  trying to create `PersistentVolume` to share directory on **master (not on nodes)** with the pods, for that, I'm using the following .yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: my-pv-volume
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  hostPath:
    path: "/home/myhostuser/shared"
```

And I have the following Deployment .yaml where I'm trying to use the shared above as follow:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-app
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
      replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-app
        image: my-app-image 
        volumeMounts:
         - mountPath: /shared_host_path
           name: my-volume
        securityContext:
          privileged: true      
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
      volumes:
      - name: my-volume
        hostPath: 
        # directory location on host
          path: "/home/myhostuser/shared/"
```

When I'm trying to run `ls /home/myhostuser/shared` on **host** as except I see files but when I run `ls /shared_host_path` inside the **pod** I not see files.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

if you want to have the volume on the master, you have to specify this in the persistentVolume specification, like this

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: my-pv-volume
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  local:
    path: /home/myhostuser/shared
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
          - master
```

this is how the Kubernetes scheduler understands that this PersistentVolume is tied to a specific node

Comment: Hi, Looks great, Can you give me example of how the pod yaml file should be to configure  this pv?

Comment: and btw, It  will work even if the pod running  on  NODE and not on MASTER?

Comment: if you want to have your local pv on master then your pods should be schedule there as well, so create your PV like this and then specify nodeName for your pods like this https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#nodename.
 you already have your example.

Answer (score 2):

Define a PVC as below

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: task-pv-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 3Gi
```

And use the PVC in deployment as below

```
  volumes:
    - name: task-pv-storage
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: task-pv-claim
  containers:
    - name: task-pv-container
      image: nginx
      ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: "http-server"
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/shared_host_path"
          name: task-pv-storage
```

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/

Comment: I'm trying to use  that but  when I try to run kubectl get pvc Its on Pending, btw its should share directory from MASTER and not from nodes?

Comment: the pod will share the directory of the node where it will be running..it's decided by the scheduler which node it will be deployed. So if you have put some content in master node and the pod runs on worker it will not see those files.

Comment: I'm tryring to share directory from master server not from nodes, Is it possible?

Comment: Check where the pod is running kubectl get pod podname -o wide.in case you want to run the pod in master there is some extra thing that need to be done to make master node schedulable for pods.

Comment: Ok,  so how  can I share directory from master even if the pod running on nodes and not on master?

Comment: there is no way to do that using hostPath volume...you can either run the pod in master or use a NFS backed volume which is not attached to a node particularly. if you want to run the pod in master I can tell you how to do that